# Angular.js upload image by copy and paste

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

I am using this photo upload directive to upload images:

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

http://jsfiddle.net/ew4jakn5/

```
 $scope.upload = function (files) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                Upload.upload({
                    url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                    fields: {
                        'username': $scope.username
                    },
                    file: file
                }).progress(function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    $scope.log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' +
                                evt.config.file.name + '\n' + $scope.log;
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $scope.log = 'file: ' + config.file.name + ', Response: ' + JSON.stringify(data) + '\n' + $scope.log;
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    };
```

I need to add the ability to 'paste' an image from the clipboard and for that to be uploaded by ng-file-upload.

Could anyone give me pointers on how to do that?

Comment: Have a look over the `contenteditable` attribute and see if you can come up with a solution. Here is something to start off with: http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/

Answer (score 2):

```
 function handlePaste(e) {
            $log.debug(e.originalEvent.clipboardData);
            for (var i = 0 ; i < e.originalEvent.clipboardData.items.length ; i++) {
                var item = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.items[i];
                console.log("Item type: " + item.type);
                if (item.type.indexOf("image") != -1) {
                    $log.debug( item.getAsFile(), {});
                    Upload.upload({file: item.getAsFile(),
                        url: '/upload/', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
                        // method: POST or PUT,
                        // headers: {'header-key': 'header-value'},
                        // withCredentials: true,
                        data: {user_uuid: $scope.session.user.user_uuid}});
                } else {
                    alert("Discarding non-image paste data");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pasting an image is the same as dropping them

```
<div class="img-dropper" ngf-drop="upload($files)" ng-model="context[terminatedkey]" ngf-drag-over-class="'dragover'"  tabindex="0">
    <span>Paste or drop files here</span>
</div>
```

and the default `$scope.upload = function (file)` will work